# React - My form is submitting empty data because 'e' and 'data' are declared but never used?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, react-hook-form

I'm trying to implement a form using [react-hook-form](https://react-hook-form.com/). I'm not able to actually connect the data and event working correctly. As the docs state, I'm using the `handleSubmit` function from the react-hook-form library, with my custom Axios post as the `onSubmit` parameter:  `onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)`

According to my Vscode, the data and event are not registering correctly `const onSubmit = (data, e) => {}`.

When the form is submitted, the web console logs an empty form:
`{email: "", password: ""}`

What am I doing wrong with my code? Note for sake of brevity, I removed the password textfield below.

```
export default function SignIn()
{
    const { register, control, errors: fieldsErrors, handleSubmit } = useForm()
    const history = useHistory();
    const initialFormData = Object.freeze({
        email: '',
        password: '',
    });

    const [formData, updateFormData] = useState(initialFormData);

    const handleChange = (e) => {
        updateFormData({
            ...formData,
        });
    };

    const dispatch = useDispatch();
    
    const onSubmit = (data, e) => {
            console.log(formData);
        
            axiosInstance
                .post(`auth/token/`, {
                    grant_type: 'password',
                    username: formData.email,
                    password: formData.password,
                })
                .then((res) => {
                    console.log(res);
                    localStorage.setItem('access_token', res.data.access_token);
                    localStorage.setItem('refresh_token', res.data.refresh_token);
                    history.push('/');
                    window.location.reload();
                    dispatch(login({
                        name: formData.email,
                        password: formData.password,
                        loggedIn: true,
                    }))
                })
        
        };

    const classes = useStyles();

    return (
        <Container component="main" maxWidth="xs">
            <CssBaseline />
            <div className={classes.paper}>
                <Typography component="h1" variant="h5">
                    Sign in
                </Typography>
                <form className={classes.form} noValidate onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
                    <FormControl fullWidth variant="outlined">
                        <Controller
                            name="email"
                            as={
                                <TextField
                                    variant="outlined"
                                    margin="normal"
                                    inputRef={register}
                                    required
                                    fullWidth
                                    id="email"
                                    label="Email Address"
                                    name="email"
                                    autoComplete="email"
                                    autoFocus
                                    onChange={handleChange}
                                    helperText={fieldsErrors.email ? fieldsErrors.email.message : null}
                                    error={fieldsErrors.email}
                                />
                            }
                            control={control}
                            defaultValue=""
                            rules={{
                                required: 'Required',
                                pattern: {
                                value: /^[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}$/i,
                                message: 'invalid email address'
                                }
                            }}
                        />  
                    </FormControl>
```

How can I link up everything correctly and get my input data and event to communicate with the  `onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)` inside my form?

Thank you for the help!

EDIT:

```
export default function SignIn()
{
    const { register, control, errors: fieldsErrors, handleSubmit } = useForm()
    const history = useHistory();
    const initialFormData = Object.freeze({
        email: '',
        password: '',
    });

    const [formData, updateFormData] = useState(initialFormData);

    const handleChange = (e) => {
        updateFormData({
          ...formData,
          ...e
        });
      };

    const dispatch = useDispatch();
    
    const onSubmit = (data, e) => {
            console.log(formData);
        
            axiosInstance
                .post(`auth/token/`, {
                    grant_type: 'password',
                    username: formData.email,
                    password: formData.password,
                })
                .then((res) => {
                    console.log(res);
                    localStorage.setItem('access_token', res.data.access_token);
                    localStorage.setItem('refresh_token', res.data.refresh_token);
                    history.push('/');
                    window.location.reload();
                    dispatch(login({
                        name: formData.email,
                        password: formData.password,
                        loggedIn: true,
                    }))
                })
        
        };


    return (
        <Container component="main" maxWidth="xs">
            <CssBaseline />
            <div className={classes.paper}>
                <Typography component="h1" variant="h5">
                    Sign in
                </Typography>
                <form className={classes.form} noValidate onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
                    <FormControl fullWidth variant="outlined">
                        <Controller
                            name="email"
                            as={
                                <TextField
                                    variant="outlined"
                                    margin="normal"
                                    inputRef={register}
                                    required
                                    fullWidth
                                    id="email"
                                    label="Email Address"
                                    name="email"
                                    autoComplete="email"
                                    autoFocus
                                    onChange={
                                        (evt) => {
                                          let key = evt.currentTarget.name;
                                          let value = evt.currentTarget.value;
                                          handleChange({[key]: value});
                                        }
                                      }
                                    helperText={fieldsErrors.email ? fieldsErrors.email.message : null}
                                    error={fieldsErrors.email}
                                />
                            }
                            control={control}
                            defaultValue=""
                            rules={{
                                required: 'Required',
                                pattern: {
                                value: /^[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}$/i,
                                message: 'invalid email address'
                                }
                            }}
                        />  
                    </FormControl>
                    <TextField
                        variant="outlined"
                        margin="normal"
                        inputRef={register}
                        required
                        fullWidth
                        name="password"
                        label="Password"
                        type="password"
                        id="password"
                        autoComplete="current-password"
                        onChange={
                            (evt) => {
                              let key = evt.currentTarget.name;
                              let value = evt.currentTarget.value;
                              handleChange({[key]: value});
                            }
                          }
                    />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not use the `data` parameter on the `onSubmit` function?

```
const onSubmit = (data, e) => {
        console.log(data);
    
        axiosInstance
            .post(`auth/token/`, {
                grant_type: 'password',
                username: data.email,
                password: data.password,
            })
            .then((res) => {
                console.log(res);
                localStorage.setItem('access_token', res.data.access_token);
                localStorage.setItem('refresh_token', res.data.refresh_token);
                history.push('/');
                window.location.reload();
                dispatch(login({
                    name: data.email,
                    password: data.password,
                    loggedIn: true,
                }))
            })
    
    };
```

Using this `Controller` component inside the `form`

```
  <Controller
    as={
      <TextField
        variant="outlined"
        margin="normal"
        fullWidth
        label="Email Address"
        autoComplete="email"
        autoFocus
        error={Boolean(fieldsErrors.email)}
      />
    }
    name="email"
    control={control}
    rules={{
      required: 'Required',
      pattern: {
      value: /^[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}$/i,
      message: 'invalid email address'
      }
    }}
    defaultValue=""
  />
  {fieldsErrors.email?.type && <p>{fieldsErrors.email?.message}</p>}
```

Answer (score 0):

`onSubmit` only has one argument in its callback function & its the `event`.. Where you can get the data using `event.target` array or `event.target.elements."fieldname"` (fieldname is the `name` of the input field) or `event.target.fieldname.value`....

**onSubmit**:

```
const onSubmit = (e) => {
            console.log(formData);
        
            axiosInstance
                .post(`auth/token/`, {
                    grant_type: 'password',
                    username: formData.target.email.value,
                    password: formData.target.password.value,
                })
                .then((res) => {
                    console.log(res);
                    localStorage.setItem('access_token', res.data.access_token);
                    localStorage.setItem('refresh_token', res.data.refresh_token);
                    history.push('/');
                    window.location.reload();
                    dispatch(login({
                        name: formData.email,
                        password: formData.password,
                        loggedIn: true,
                    }))
                })
        
        };
```

Well, just remove the `data` parameter...

Comment: Hi, thank you for the comment. Please see these docs: https://react-hook-form.com/api#handleSubmit  The `onSubmi`t requires two parameters, `data` and `e`. I've tried only having `e`, and I'm still getting the same problem as mentioned in my post.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at

```
const handleChange = (e) => {
    updateFormData({
        ...formData,
    });
};
```

and

```
<TextField
...
onChange={handleChange}
...
/>
```

It seems like the onChange simply isn't changing the state. You're probably going to want to do something like this:

```
onChange={
  (evt) => {
    let key = evt.currentTarget.name;
    let value = evt.currentTarget.value;
    handleChange({[key]: value});
  }
}
```

and then

```
const handleChange = (e) => {
  updateFormData({
    ...formData,
    ...e
  });
};
```

This should work for the password field if the "name" attribute is "password".

Comment: Please see my edit in the original post, I've implented your example but still cant get the code to work. I'm not getting a `{email: "", password: "", undefined: "password"}` as a response, with  an undefined field now being generated? Can you confirm if I implemented your method correctly?

Comment: @Dre You want to change `let key = evt.currentTarget.password` to `let key = evt.currentTarget.name` in the onChange attribute. Same mistake is in the email input field. :)

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out :). I'm managed to get the proper response for my password field in the console, but my email field is still empty? Even though I've changed to the fixes you've mentioned? Ive again edited my original post to show the changes Ive made.

Comment: @Dre Hmm... there's no errors showing up either? If not, could you try replacing the `let key = evt.currentTarget.name` inside the email onChange with `let key = 'email'` and see if that forces it to work?

Comment: No errors, also your recommendation sadly did not work as well. I think the problem is coming from how I'm handling the errors? Password field has no validation or error message/rules, compared email field. Yet password field is working fine in the response.

Comment: @Dre That sounds like it might be the case. Unfortunately I'm not too familiar with validation rules. I also saw in the `react-hook-form` docs that `as` is soon-to-be deprecated and that `render` is the new thing to replace it. That might be worth a shot? Hope you find a solution.

Comment: Nonetheless thank you for helping me be closer to solving this issue!